# Is there any in-app linemode equivalent of "vim -r"?

Tags: vim, recover, swapfile

I would like to view the available swap files in the usual directories (home, tmp, etc.) as well as the current working folder.

What can I do? I've seen `:h :recover`, but that seems to only be suitable for cases when you have a particular swapfile in mind to recover. Is there any that will present me with all the options as `vim -r` does?

Comment: You can try [persistent undo](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2012/07/26/persistent-undo-history-in-vim/) and then you can [time travel](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:echo globpath(&dir, '.*.sw?')
```

The `'directory'` option (short form `'dir'`) lists the directories where vim tries to create swap files.  On some systems, swap files may not start with <kbd>.</kbd>, so you would modify the filename pattern accordingly.

If you want to do more than just view the available swap files, you could start with

```
:let swapfiles = globpath(&dir, '.*.sw?')
:let swapfilelist = split(swapfiles, "\n")
```

(I think that the `"\n"` works on all systems.)

```
:help globpath()
:help swap-file
:help 'directory'
:help expr-option
:help split()
```